# Managing persistence sessions in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

i'm trying to set up a very basic session manager. So, first i came with this code:

```
 var session     = require('express-session');
 var MongoStore   = require('connect-mongo')(session);

// define session store
app.use(session({
    secret: 'meh',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
       db : 'express'
    })
}));
```

My current setup is nodejs/express4 with all modules installed locally.
now, how can i share this app without having problems with connect-mongo? because, if i run it on other machine, i get this error:

```
 "error connection to database:failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]..."
```

Do you know what may be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious mistake here would be: there is no running MongoDB instance on the other machine.

If you want to connect to a remote server you have to specify the location and (hopefully) credentials. Have a look at: https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#options

Comment: sure, but how can i start a new instance of mongodb on each different machine?
there is no remote server in this case. each user, will run this app on their machine, so, i just want a new instance.. 
makes sense?

Comment: Then you have to bundle mongodb to your application and start it when you start the app, and kill it when you close the app. See: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html (I don't recomend this). Otherwise you have to implement a centralized way to handle your data (API, remote DB) or store it without mongodb by using simply a file via fs-module.

Comment: i'm little bit confused on this.. imagine this scenario. I have problems with my computer..  i download it again from my repository and i can't work with it in other computer? even in development enviroment?

Comment: You can provide a seperate test database and make it available from outside (I recomend that) or use a tool like this https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongojs for testing.